# changing directory in shell using c++ program

Tags: c++, ubuntu

I need to change directory in shell

```
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
cout<<system("cd ..")<<endl; 
return 0;
}
```

now i understand that that this wont work. My question is, what are my other options.
thanks

Comment: I don't know for c++, but with c you'd use `chdir` from unistd.h

Comment: that changes the working directory. i need to execute command on shell.

Comment: um yes… you can only ever change the working directory of the current process (and subsequently its subprocesses). You cannot change the working directory of the invoking process/shell.

Comment: ahan.. chdir would do for any practicality. i was just practicing with stuff thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the working directory of another process.

Answer (score 4):

Each process (so your program too) has its own current directory. When you invoke `system("cd ..")` then a separate process is executed (in ubuntu it is `bash` I believe) and that process is executing command `cd ..`, so it is changing its own current directory, and than it ends. What you want to do is change current directory of your own process (program), what you shoud do is :

```
#include <unistd.h>
chdir("..");
```

Obviously put the `include` directive at the beginning of your file :)

Comment: Probably because that doesn't do what the OP wants!

Answer (score 0):

The best solution, that used official by file manager [nnn](https://github.com/jarun/nnn), is to use a `tmp-file`.

- Process father, invoke `proces` child,
- Process child create `Shell file` in `tmp-dir` then exit
- /tmp/tmp/file-exemple

```bash
# somthing like
cd /am/in/this/path
```

- Process father, source this `file`

```bash
export NNN_TMPFILE="/tmp/nnn"

n()
{
    nnn "$@"

    if [ -f $NNN_TMPFILE ]; then
        . $NNN_TMPFILE
        rm $NNN_TMPFILE
    fi
}
```